# how to map dictionary keys to variables in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a game that saves information such as funds and stuff like that about users in a shelve. That shelve starts out looking something like this:

```
Userdata = shelve.open('UserData', writeback = True)
Userdata[username]={'funds' = 100, 
                    'highscore' = 0}
```

The username variable is defined earlier. The shelve has keys that are usernames, and the values are dictionaries with that user's data. And then, I have some in-game variables that correspond to the values stored in the dictionary:

```
funds = Userdata[username]['funds']
highscore = Userdata[username]['highscore']
```

The variables in the dictionary get changed as the user changes the in-game values. The names of the variables will always be the same as the corresponding dictionary key. The problem is, I have quite a few variables in the dictionary. I was wondering if there was a way to map the variables to the corresponding keys in the dictionary in a for loop or something, so that I don't have to define every single one? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need them in a variable name if you're not willing to type it out?  By adding them with a for loop you'd likely create a bunch of variables you aren't actually going to use  Is there a reason that using them in data stores that are keyed on strings don't work for you?

Comment: IMHO your variables are too small. They should be members of a class and then you have `userstate = Userdata[username]` only. You'd then access the funds using `userstate.funds` and the highscore by `userstate.highscore`.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasWeller,if your data loaded from shelve is a json string, you could use json module to parse to a dict, then you can use `userstate.funds` to arrive the member variable

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you! I just started writing the whole thing again as a class, and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scope you can use `globals` or `locals` for this:

```
In [1]: d = {'funds': 100, 'highscore': 0}
   ...: for k in d:
   ...:     locals()[k] = d[k]

In [2]: funds
Out[2]: 100

In [3]: highscore
Out[3]: 0
```